# css hover problem when including an html5 video in chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to use the html5 video tag for a page but I discovered that the hover is not working properly. The version of my Google Chrome is 10.0.648.133, and my OS is Windows 7.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOOEx.png

But when I remove the video from the page it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks! I'll appreciate your help. :)

Here's my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chrome mp4 video player test</title>

<style type="text/css"> 
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

div.with_hover:hover {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
</div>

<div class="with_hover">
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. Do you have an absolute url to test.mp4?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @tilleryj Thanks for your help. :) I'm sorry but I don't have an absolute url. I uploaded the file here: http://www.mediafire.com/?r1v3bemn38lh6uu

Comment: @Lime 10.0.648.133, my OS is Windows 7

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce it. Maybe try clearing your cache. What does it look like when not hovering? Does the issue go away if you remove the video?

Comment: @tilleryj Thanks for helping me. Yes, the hover is fine when the video is removed from the page. This is how it looks like when it is not hovered: http://i.imgur.com/MJByt.png (there is still background color even if it is not hovered, really weird). May I know what version of Chrome you're using? Thanks, I'm using 10.0.648.133.

Comment: @tilleryj Thanks so much, I tried it in Ubuntu but it works fine, I could only see this problem in Windows 7. I also tried clear my cache, but the problem is still there. Again, thanks for your time helping me. :D

Comment: Hmmm, that's a weird bug. I bet you can fix it with some trial and error. Try setting the background color of .with_hover to #fff when not in a hover state. Try wrapping the with_hover div in another div with a white background. Try moving the links above the video to see if that changes anything. Maybe try changing the display property...

Comment: Does it repro in Chrome 11 (the current stable build)?

Comment: @SteveLacey No, it doesn't repro in Chrome 11.0.696.71 :) Thanks for asking

Comment: It would help if you told us what you would like to happen when it hovers. Also, your code shows two different hover definitions. Which of them is your question regarding?

Answer (score -1):

After the video's completion, and after you stop hovering the controls disappear and you can't get them to come back. If you remove the link to the mp4 file it will no longer happen.